# Python: Selecting rows matching Feb till current month in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have below dataframe:

```
Name1   Name2   Month   Mode    Value1 Value2
A       N       Sep     Plan    9       9
B       N       Nov     Plan    6       6
B       N       Jan     Plan    6       6
C       N       Feb     Actual  4       4
C       N       Jul     Actual  3       3
D       N       May     Plan    2       2
E       N       Apr     Actual  6       6
F       N       Feb     Actual  7       7
E       N       May     Actual  4       4
F       N       Jun     Plan    3       3
<+ 100 more rows>
```

Considering the current month is June, the expected output is as follows:

```
Name1   Name2   Mode    Value1  Value2
C       N       Actual    4       4                                             
D       N       Plan      2       2                                             
E       N       Actual    10      10                                                
F       N       Actual    7       7                                             
F       N       Plan      3       3
```

Here i have done filtering of rows  by months from Feb:Current Month (in this case June) and then group by to find all the names once per mode. (Example: F will be only once for actual and once for plan)

I previously tried taking a transpose of columns and then using the below to summarize the data till current month:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name1':df['Name1'], 'previous_mt':df.loc[:,prev_month], 'current_mt':df.loc[:,this_month]})
```

where :

```
    prev = curr_month.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
    prev_month = prev.strftime("%B")[:3]

    curr_month = dt.datetime.now()
    this_month = curr_month.strftime("%B")[:3]
```

But this is getting very complicated since the actual data has lots and lots of modes and also many years of data. Is there any easier solution for the same where this complication can be avoided and the similar solution can be achieved?

In the end i am expecting to have the below dataframe:

```
Name1   Name2   Actual_Value1   Actual_Value2   Plan_Value1 Plan_Value1
C       N           4              4                            
D       N                                           2             2         
E       N           10             10                               
F       N           7              7                3             3
```

I guess i can have this format using pivot_table in pandas:

```
df=pd.pivot_table(df_input,index=['Name1', 'Name2'], 
                      columns=['Mode'],
                      values=['Value1', 'Value2'], 
                      aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0).reset_index().rename_axis(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Pandas, use **pivot_table** to transpose table data (rows become columns).
- Be sure to use **reset_index()** to convert the pivot object to a dataframe

Based on your sample dataset, this code gave the results you're looking for:

```
lstAllMonths=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
curMth = datetime.today().month  # 7=July
curMth = 6  # Jun for testing
lstMth = lstAllMonths[1:curMth]

df = df[df['Month'].isin(lstMth)][['Name1','Name2','Mode','Value1','Value2']]
gb = df.groupby(['Name1','Name2','Mode'])
dfagg = gb.agg({'Value1':sum, 'Value2':sum})

dfpvt = pd.pivot_table(dfagg,index=['Name1', 'Name2'], 
                      columns=['Mode'],
                      values=['Value1', 'Value2'], 
                      aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0).reset_index().rename_axis(1)
                      
dfpvt.columns=['Name1','Name2','Actual_Value1','Plan_Value1','Actual_Value2','Plan_Value2']
dfpvt.replace(0,'', inplace=True)
dfpvt = dfpvt[['Name1','Name2','Actual_Value1','Actual_Value2','Plan_Value1','Plan_Value2']]    
print(dfpvt)
```